# ThinkPad OneLink ProDock with ThinkPad Yoga

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad

I have a ThinkPad Yoga, the one from last year and the Pro Dock of ThinkPad. I'd love to install Ubuntu on the Yoga, which should work fine from what I've seen. The question is, if the Pro Dock has full driver support in Ubuntu. Does anyone know?

I've read a few things but I still don't know if everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I have a ThinkPad Edge E540 and I just bought OneLink Pro Dock. Everything works fine - USB, sound, DVI... (I have not tested DP yet) except ethernet. Ubuntu finds OneLink Pro Dock ethernet adapter, but I can't connect to the internet. I have to plug the LAN cable to the laptop to get online.

There is some patch https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1291890 , but it does not work for me.